# How to add new Icon to CSS class for HTML element

Tags: html, css

I would to add my Icon from another link to HTML element, and its clickable.

The icon associated with class, class name icon.

[image: How to add my icon to HTML element, like this]

`<a href="#" class="icon" title="shareStatus"></a>`

**Note:**
I need to take icon from another source.

Your suggestion will be advisable

Comment: add background image to .icon class like this in style sheet background-image: url("url here");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution like the following, using a background image:

```css
.icon {
  content:"";
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="icon" title="shareStatus"></a>
```